# c++ подстановка в шаблоны, шаблон в шаблоне

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, метапрограммирование, rvalue, sfinae

Всем привет! Хотелось бы понять, как инстанцируются шаблоны в шаблонах классов. Ниже приведу пример(он **абстрактный**, если там будут ошибки, **не** связанные с шаблонами, то просто игнорируем их):

```
template<typename T>
struct myobj
{
T* i;
myobj()
{
}
template<Ty>
Ty foo(Ty param)
{
//...do something...
}
};

int main()
{
myobj A;
A.foo(5);
A.foo(5.25);
return 0;
}
```

Будут ли созданы 2 перегруженных метода?
И что делать с проверками условий? Например я хочу, чтобы функции(методы) создавались только когда Ty совпадает с T с помощью enable_if_t и прочих type traits, но с правильным(т.е. именно тем, который был для класса, откуда вызываем метод) ли T будет сверяться условие, если я создам много классов с разными Т?
P.S. и что делать с сворачиванием универсальных ссылок? Чтобы в данном классе был примерно такой метод:

```
template<Ty, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, Ty>::value, typename std::nullptr_t> =nullptr>
Ty foo(Ty&& param)
{
//do something...
}
```

В такой ситуации при попытке постановки в Ty и сверки T и Ty с помощью is_same Ty рассматривается например как double&(ну или просто просто ссылочный тип, а не обычный), а не просто А.(если есть ошибки в использовании type trait-ов, то заранее извиняюсь за них)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на первый вопрос — да, конечно, будут созданы две функции-члена.

По второму вопросу — я не уверен, что обошел все подводные камни, и что вообще это правильный подход, но как вариант

```
typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::remove_cvref_t<T>,
                                       std::remove_cvref_t<Ty>>::value, 
                          typename std::nullptr_t> = nullptr
```

ну т.е. просто убираем все `const/volatile/reference` и сравниваем типы без них.

Или то же с концептами:

```
template< typename Ty> requires same_as<remove_cvref_t<T>,remove_cvref_t<Ty>>
```

Comment: а из-за чего вообще Ty становится ссылочным при передачах в шаблоны, если Ty по идее должен быть самым обычным?

Comment: Как я понимаю, потому что вы хотите ссылочный тип (универсальную ссылку). Если написать просто `Ty`, должно попустить, как я понимаю...

Comment: Ну вот у меня реальный пример ошибки: `no matching function for call to fastvector<A>::append(A&)`, хотя я вызываю `myvec.append(myA);` где `myA` самый обычный объект типа `А`.  `std::remove_cvref_t` помогает, да, но откуда там вообще взялась ссылка, которую таким образом убираем?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, вы сами требуете передачу по ссылке? Как у вас объявлена функция `append`?

Comment: Да, и самое главное, что компилятор не нашел append по непонятной причине. Вот как она выглядит: `template <typename Ty, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, Ty>::value, typename std::nullptr_t> =nullptr>
    void append(Ty&& object)` Ty 100% совпадает с Т, но почему-то компилятор этого не понимает, с `remove_cvref_t` уже находит

Comment: Универсальная ссылка автоматом обнаруживает, что передано — l-value или r-value, вот и при передаче переменной соображает, что это же l-value, а значит, надо рассматривать как ссылку...

Comment: это верно,но ведь преобразуется только тип аргумента функции(T&&),а не сам Ty, разве нет?